# When using 'tabs' on a webpage, how can you determine which tab will be visible when a user clicks the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have a web page which used a tab system (similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)) which uses JavaScript to determine which aspects of the pages content is visible.

If a particular tab is visible, and from this tab the user clicks a link - but then clicks the back button, how can I make it so that they are not only taken back to the same page - but with the same information visible?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You could use [`history API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), which is SEO friendly, hash navigation (`#`) but it will create multiple *history* entries (click on multiple tabs will require multiple `back` clicks) or even cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There's alot of frameworks out there that sloves this (angular, backbone.js etc). If you want to build it your self you need to update the url (for the back button to work), either by adding a hash tag (eg. #tab1) to the end of the url or by using the History API.

Using the hash tag as an example:

Your tab links and view needs to look like this :

```
<a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>

<div class="tabcontent" id="tab1">Content 1</div>
<div class="tabcontent" id="tab2">Content 2</div>
```

And your JS function need to display the active tab based on what is in your hash tag and when it changes:

An example using jQuery:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  $('.tabcontent').hide();
  $(window.location.hash).show();
});
```